# Counter that counts in a loop of multiples

Tags: digital-logic

[image]I need to design a counter that counts in a loop of 5 mult: 0-5-10.. My attempt is down below but I`m not sure how to form the kmap for every D ff as I have 5 current states and we never worked with a 5 var kmap so im assuming it has to be done some other way.It s first year digital logic so a simple counter is requested.

Comment: 4 bits are sufficient to count to 16, or you could build a Johnson counter with 5.  I'm not sure what the first sentence actually means.

Comment: Need to make a counter to count up to 30 in the loop of multiples of 5 0-5-10-15-20-25-30 doesnt ths require 5 bits

Comment: As I understand the question, what is wanted logically is a modulo-5 counter, followed by another counter to count overflows. (This is easy to do in practice with standard counter ICs.) It is not clear what form the output should take - units, '5's, '25's would be correct for modulo-5 arithmetic. Define the output format to get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: there's only 7 steps...  3 bits are enough

Comment: There are a number of ways this could be done. (1) Use a microcomputer (2) use an adder (3) follow a (3 bit) binary counter with a ROM (4) decode the output of a binary counter using gates (5) use a modulo 5 counter with another binary counter and latch outputs.

Comment: `simple counter is requested` ...  why are you asking us to do your homework for you?